# Linux:How to tweak TSO and GSO from proc window / sysctl

Tags: linux, tcp

OS:`CentOS 5`
I am doing some TCP optimization on my Linux box and want to put `ON` `tcp segmentation offload` and `generic segmentation offload`. I am doing it through `ethtool`
Here is what I am doing:

```
ethtool -k eth1
Offload parameters for eth1:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
scatter-gather: on
tcp segmentation offload: on
udp fragmentation offload: off
generic segmentation offload: off
```

I've done this through

```
#ethtool -K eth1 tso on
```

Further I am interested to know that how parameters are modified through `ethtool`.

- What parameters are affected under `/proc` while `ethtool -K` operation ?
- Is there any way to do the same thing with `sysctl`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my knowledge you can enable TSO/GSO from the given commands.

> Is there any way to do the same thing with sysctl?

```
sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.tso=1
sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.tso=1
```

> What parameters are affected under /proc while ethtool -K operation?

Usually `sysctl` is better to change the value as it reads the contents of `/etc/sysctl.conf` which allows to keep the value save even after the system is restart.

Comment: It seems above are for FreeBSD based system. Not worked with linux.